# How to determine testing and training accuracy of different folds in 10 fold cross validation using caret package in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I am using Caret package in R studio. I want to run 10-Fold CV on my dataset in order to perform a linear regression analysis. I fit the model as below:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
output <- train(Species~., data=iris, trControl=train_control, method="lm")
```

The above code just gives the over all RMSE or Rsquared scores across the 10 folds.

```
output$resample
```

The above code gives me the testing scores over different folds which is fine.

Q1: Now my question is how can I similarly find the training scores over these different folds?

Q2: What does the below command gives? Is it the over all testing scores over all the folds?

```
getTrainPerf(output)
```

Q3: How can I estimate the intercept and weights of each fold? Moreover, the below code just gives me the over-all intercept and weights across all folds. How is this computed? Is it simply averaged across all the folds again?

```
output$finalModel
```

Reference: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/how-to-get-sub-training-and-sub-test-from-cross-validation-in-caret/114224